# How to write a good birth scene?

Tags: technique, originality

I would like to do a mystical pregnancy for a story, with the female as the main character. One of the gods from the world pantheon wishes to be reincarnated into the physical realm in order to experience what it is like to be human. Due to ancient laws made eons ago, gods cannot enter the realm in their true form. He proposes the woman allow herself to be used as a conduit to be born into the mortal world in exchange for power, which she accepts.

I would like to write this from the mother's perspective, and differentiate it from a normal birth. How can i write this in a way to make it unique?

Comment: I'd say make it unlike a real birth scene. In my experience many people don't want to read about birth. I'd say make it as mystical as you can, go the opposite to what you are suggesting, since you're dealing with a god, why not?

Comment: Ugh, more breeding fantasy. IMO it is already tacky/cheesy, and you've said she does this as a power transaction – not from love or piety – so you've forfeit any traditional emotions about childbirth. Agree with @DPT. The god can make the whole experience seem like a trip to the day spa or eating chocolate cake or swimming in a cloud of gold glitter. Women like shoes so make her experience it like shoe shopping, just make it surprising and weird and wonderful, and be sure to keep her eye on that gold digger Power prize or you'll be derailing your godly premise with banal body functions.

Comment: Some women like shoes and some men like shoes. And others don't. Just want to make sure that's clear.

Comment: Helen of Troy was hatched from an egg…. I'd say "mystical" is relative to how imaginative your gods are.

Comment: Just to give some ideas: [Nativity of Jesus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nativity_of_Jesus)

Comment: @DPT as a woman who has no interest in shoes, clothes, handbags, chocolate or trips to the spa, thank you for standing up to that grating stereotype. If I picked up a book where childbirth was likened to a trip to the shoe shop, I think I'd burn it. Then again, if I had to choose, I'd rather give birth than go shoe shopping! Far less painful and dull! ;)

Comment: I'd start the story with the birth, as if it's a normal one, only to reveal later what really happened. The mother's bound to have somewhat unusual feelings because of the circumstances, which the reader will find puzzling but intriguing if it's handled well. If she tells the story (or that part of it) in first person, you can show that she feigns more normalcy in her feelings than is genuine, which makes it all the more enticing for readers.

Answer (score -3):

Please have some respect for womans birth rights.

If anything, by accepting such a power she should be subject to severe pain.
Don't curse or burden her by doing such a thing any further.

I would make it a difficult, strenuous and heart gripping pregnancy ONLY in the story that you are writing which in no way affects any body else.

I think that the most important thing is conveying the fact that there is transgressions and that they are accepted and forgiven.

It should be breath taking.  Perhaps you could write a stark contrast.  Set it against an Earthen , green scene..colourful sky..not sure if this is on another planet...but I am kind of thinking like Avatar without the whole conflict.

Propped up by roses and greenery but in a pain that perhaps makes her black out and have visions of these gods and their realm and her having a message passed on to her so she seeks a higher calling.